# Read files searching for a string and print its path

Tags: string, perl, file, search

I am trying to write a script in Perl that searches in a particular directory and all the subdirectories. The objective for this is that the script has to read all the files in the directory and all subdirectories looking for a particular text string (any string I define). If the string is found in the file then the script prints the path and name of the file in a new text file, and continues with all the files in the directory tree.

I have somenthing like this, but I am not sure on how to continue. I am a beginner with Perl, and have no clue on all the options of this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use File::Find;

my $dir = 'C:\PATH\TO\DIR';
my $string = "defined";

find(\&printFile, $dir);
sub printFile {
   my $element = $_;
   open FILE, "+>>Results.txt";
   if(-f $elemento && $elemento =~ /\.txt$/) {
       my $boolean = 0;
       open CFILE, $elemento;
       while(<CFILE>) {  
           if ($string) {
               print FILE "$File::Find::name\n"; 
           }
           close CFILE;
      }
   }
   close FILE;
}

sleep(5);
```

Comment: Perhaps you would prefer to use one of the many implementations `grep` instead of rolling your own.

Comment: As said above, you can use Perl's `grep()` function. Also from experience I recommend you to output to STDIN instead of a file (just `print()` it). You can redirect the output to a file using `>` redirection. This allows more flexibity to the script (for example piping the output to another process, etc...).

Comment: I have tried using grep, but it didn´t give me the results I wanted, as it didn´t show me all the subdirectories contained. That´s why I am trying to look for another solution.

Comment: @m0skit0: Perl's `grep` won't do that: it filters Perl lists not files. And you can't output to `STDIN` :)

Comment: Ok I understood the question wrong. I thought the string was in the file **name** :P

Answer (score 2):

You are not too far off, however there are some things you need to change.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;  # never go without warnings
use File::Find;

my $dir = 'C:\PATH\TO\DIR';
my $string = "defined";
open my $out, ">>", "Results.txt" or die $!;  # move outside, change mode, 
                                              # 3-arg open, check return value
find(\&printFile, $dir);

sub printFile {
   my $element = $_;
   if(-f $element && $element =~ /\.txt$/) { # $elemento doesn't exist
       open my $in, "<", $element or die $!;
       while(<$in>) {
           if (/\Q$string\E/) {  # make a regex and quote metachars 
               print $out "$File::Find::name\n"; 
               last;             # stop searching once found
           }
      }
   }  # lexical file handles auto close when they go out of scope
}
```

Even better would be to forgo the hard coded values and skip the specific output file:

```
my $dir = shift;
my $string = shift;
```

And then just print output to STDOUT.

```
print "$File::Find::name\n";
```

Usage:

```
perl script.pl c:/path/to/dir > output.txt
```

As others have noted in the comments, this would easily be solved with a recursive [`grep`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep). But unfortunately you seem to be using Windows, in which case it is not an option (as far as I know).

Comment: Thank you TLP its work perfectly.  Then you can explain `if(-f $element && $element =~ /\.txt$/)` what the mean of `-f` .?

Comment: It is described in [`perldoc -f "-X"`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

Answer (score 1):

If this is truly all you need to do, you might look at [`ack`](http://betterthangrep.com). It will search subdirectories by default, as well as other enhancements over grep. Of course if this is to a larger Perl script then you can shell out to it, or use one of the other posted answers.

```
$ ack include
```

will return something like

```
src/draw.c
27:#include <stdio.h>
28:#include <stdlib.h>
29:#include "parsedef.h"
31:#include "utils.h"
32:#include "frac.h"
33:#include "sscript.h"

src/utils.c
27:#include <stdio.h>
28:#include <stdlib.h>
29:#include <string.h>
```

... and so on

if instead you only want the names of the files with matches use the `-l` flag

```
$ ack -l include

lib/Text/AsciiTeX.xs
src/limit.c
src/sscript.c
src/dim.c
src/frac.c
src/brace.c
src/symbols.c
src/sqrt.c
src/array.c
src/ouline.c
src/draw.c
src/utils.c
src/asciiTeX.c
```

Answer (score 0):

The `#!` line is irrelevant on Windows platforms, and only a convenience on Unix. It is best if you omit it here.

Your program is mostly correct, but avoids a lot of conveniences that Perl provides to make the code more concise and comprehensible.

You should always add `use warnings` to your `use strict` as it will pick up simple errors that you may otherwise overlook.

Your file opens should use lexical file handles and the three-parameter form of `open`, and you should check their success as a failure to open a file invalidates most subsequent code. An idiomatic open looks like this

```
open my $fh, '<', 'myfile' or die $!;
```

It is also worh pointing out that an open mode of `+>>` opens the file for *both* read *and* append, which is difficult to nadle. In this case you mean just `>>`, but it is best to open the file once and leave it open for the duration of the program run.

This is a reworking of your program, which I hope helps you. It uses a regular expression to check whether the string appears in the current line of the file. `/\Q$string/` is identical to `$_ =~ /\Q$string/`, i.e. it tests the `$_` variable by default. The `\Q` in the regex is a `quotemeta`, which escapes any characters in the string that might otherwise behave as special characters in a regex and change the meaning of the search.

Note that, within the `File::Find` `wanted` subroutine, `$_` the current working directory is set to the directory containg the current file being reported. `$_` is set to the file name (without a path) and `$File::Find::name` is set to the full absolue file and path. Because the current directory is the one containing the file, it is easy just to open the file `$_` as the path isn't needed.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

my $dir = 'C:\path\to\dir';
my $string = 'defined';

open my $results, '>', 'results.txt' or die "Unable to open results file: $!";

find (\&printFile, $dir);

sub printFile {

  return unless -f and /\.txt$/;

  open my $fh, '<', , $_ or do {
    warn qq(Unable to open "$File::Find::name" for reading: $!);
    return;
  };

  while ($fh) {
    if (/\Q$string/) {
       print $results "$File::Find::name\n";
       return;
    }
  }
}
```